# Reading data in batches and updating them in EF core

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to read data in batches, 1k by 1k, until everything is processed.

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<IEnumerable<MyData>> GetData()
{
        var data = dbContext.MyTable.AsNoTracking().Where(d => d.Status == 2);
        int totalDataCount = await data.CountAsync();
        int processedData = 0;
        
        while (processedData < totalDataCount)
        {
            var currentData = await data.Take(999).ToListAsync();
            processedData += invoiceData.Count;

            yield return currentData;
        }
}
```

I'm not sure if the *NoTracking* flag is maybe causing the issue here for the same data to be loaded again and again.
Consuming code:

```
await foreach (var data in myRepository.GetData())
{
    dbContext.ChangeTracker.Clear();
    
    await dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync($@"
    UPDATE ""MyTable""
    SET
    ""Status"" = 1
    WHERE ""Id"" in ({string.Join(',', data.Select(d => d.Id))}));
}
```

So, is the *NoTracking* maybe a problem, as the queried data won't be detected as changed? Or the consuming code should include transation with its *Commit* method after the raw sql update?

Comment: The code has several problems `data` isn't data, it's a query. The query gest executed when you call something that produces results, eg `CountAsync()` or iterating over its results. The code you wrote calls the same query inside a loop.

Comment: What are you trying to do though? Why use an ORM at all if you don't intend to use objects? Why not write and execute a SQL query directly? How much data is there? ORMS are *completely* unsuitable for ETL jobs as the only relevant Entities in an ETL job are Row, Field, Transformation, Table etc.

Comment: With EF Core 7, you have `ExecuteUpdate`, for older versions there are a tons of extensions which will execute this query in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

**AsNoTracking()** might be a problem, but **Take(999)** will deliver the first 999 entries, every time!

The information found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/pagination, might lead you to a better solution.